# convert .dat to logging file from CANoe

Tags: canoe, dat-protocol

I want to open a .dat file from INCA in CANoe but for that I need to convert it into a logging file format: ascii, blf, mdf4.... does anybody know how to do it? I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Please provide a syntax definition for the dat file, maybe we can work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an option in ETAS menu bar.
Check under `Utilities > Measure Data Converter`.
You can select the file required to be converted and also which format you need to convert to.